# How can I solve this PHP issue with GET[] from my URL

Tags: php, ssl

```
if (isset($_GET['debug'])) {
    if(boolval($_GET['debug']) ? true : false)
    {
        echo "Using Distribution Certificate";
        stream_context_set_option($ctx, 'ssl', 'local_cert','cert.pem');
        $fp = stream_socket_client('ssl://gateway.push.apple.com:2195', $err, $errstr, 60, STREAM_CLIENT_CONNECT|STREAM_CLIENT_PERSISTENT, $ctx);
    } else {
        echo "Using Development Certificate";
        stream_context_set_option($ctx, 'ssl', 'local_cert','certdevelopment.pem');
        $fp = stream_socket_client('ssl://gateway.sandbox.push.apple.com:2195', $err, $errstr, 60, STREAM_CLIENT_CONNECT|STREAM_CLIENT_PERSISTENT, $ctx);
    }
}else{
    // Fallback behaviour goes here
    echo "Fallback Call To Use Distribution Certificate";
    stream_context_set_option($ctx, 'ssl', 'local_cert','cert.pem');
    $fp = stream_socket_client('ssl://gateway.push.apple.com:2195', $err, $errstr, 60, STREAM_CLIENT_CONNECT|STREAM_CLIENT_PERSISTENT, $ctx);
}
```

When my URL is https://localhost/index.php?debug=true

I want to use the Distribution Certificate. If it's false then use the Development Certificate.

If anything else is there then we use the Distribution certificate.

Unfortunately when my PHP script executes, it is always using the "Distribution Certificate". even when I set it to false. I think the "boolval" method is not working all the time.

Comment: `boolval` doesn't do what you think it does.  It *casts* the value passed to it as a boolean.  In PHP, the strings `"true"` and `"false"` both cast to boolean true.  See: http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.boolean.php#language.types.boolean.casting

Comment: Because the string `true` will always be true. It's a string an thus will be evaluated to true(an empty string is false).

Comment: P.S. You can just do `if(boolval($_GET['debug']))`, there's no reason to use `?:` here.

Comment: so how can i make it so that I can specify a parameter (true or false).

Answer (score 2):

Instead of

```
if(boolval($_GET['debug']) ? true : false)
```

You should compare the values using

```
if($_GET['debug'] == 'true')
```

This is because both "true" and "false" evaluate to true when cast to a boolean. Check the [test cases in the manual](http://php.net/manual/en/function.boolval.php) for more examples.